# Problem following exercise in Jonathan Stark's book

Tags: jquery, ios, jqtouch, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I was reading and following along exercise in Jonathan Stark's [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805784/).

I am having some error in the error console but I doesn't know how to fix it.

```
Could not find an element with the id "jqt", so the body id has been set to "jqt". If you are having any problems, wrapping your panels in a div with the id "jqt" might help.  jqtouch.js:104
```

I am using jQTouch b3.1

Please help
Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems more like a warning than an error. I suspect you're using a later version of jQTouch than the one in the book. Earlier version of jQT has pages directly under `body`, e.g.

```
<body>
  <div id="page1"></div>
  <div id="page2"></div>
</body>
```

But later version of jQT has pages under `div#jqt`, so to allow the inclusion of a fixed navigation bar, e.g. tabbar control:

```
<body>
  <div id="jqt">
    <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- you could have something fixed navigation element here -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Look like it work. I wrap the whole <body> section with a jqt div tag!

Comment: You need to post a separate question for that, as it's completed different from what you have asked...

Comment: BTW, if I have answered your question, you may want to mark it accordingly, so it will be beneficial to both askers and answerers.